# The JAVA_HOME environment variable (C:\Program\Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40) does not point to a JDK

Tags: java, visual-studio

Buenoas dias quisiera saber porque no me deja ejecutar si ya instale todas las extensiones.estuve mirando los requerimiento de debbuger y me dice que me falta el jdk  ya lo descargue como puedo configurarlo en visual studio code o es otro el error
.
gracias por la ayuda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debe apuntar al directorio `bin`dentro del jdk

Comment: No debes configurarlo en visual studio code, debes configurarlo en tu sistema operativo, pues es una variable de entorno. Te recomiendo que abras google y busques cómo settear la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME para tu sistema operativo. Hay mil tutoriales para hacerlo y es absurdamente sencillo, pero es un paso sin el cual java no funciona :)

Comment: muchas gracias lo buscare

Answer (score 1):

Para configurar correctamente la variable JRE_HOME o JAVA_HOME:

Localiza el directorio de instalación de Java

Si no cambiaste la ruta durante la instalación, será algo como

> C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

También puedes escribir "where java" en el símbolo del sistema.

- Windows 7: haz click con el botón derecho en Mi PC y seleccione Propiedades > Avanzado
- Windows 8: Panel de control > Sistema > Configuración avanzada del sistema
- Windows 10: busca variables de entorno y luego selecciona Editar las variables de entorno del sistema

Haz click en el botón Variables de entorno.

En Variables del sistema, haz click en Nuevo si JRE_HOME o JAVA_HOME no existe.

En el campo Nombre de la variable, ingresa:

> JAVA_HOME si instaló el JDK (Java Development Kit)

> JRE_HOME si instaló JRE (Java Runtime Environment)

En el campo Valor variable, ingresa la ruta de instalación JDK o JRE.

Si la ruta contiene espacios, utilice el nombre de ruta abreviado. Por ejemplo,

> C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

Nota para usuarios de Windows en sistemas de 64 bits:

> Progra~1 = 'Archivos de programa'

> Progra~2 = 'Archivos de programa (x86)'

Haz clic en Aceptar y Aplicar cambios

*Referencia: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html*